# Using Pex To Test Self Hosted WCF Service

Tags: wcf, pex

I have a scenario where I am using Self hosted WCF Services and all the methods that I wan't to Test are in that service. Now I can't find a way to test that service with PEX as it is self hosted and is not running when I try to use PEX to generate test cases for it. If I run it first then PEX does not work properly and asks me to Stop Debugging first. I wan't to know how can I use PEX in this scenario.